# How to express the code with lambda?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want convert a List to a Map

```
public Map<Integer, A> toMap(List<A> list) {
    Map<Integer, A> map = new HashMap<>();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getKey() != 0) {
            sum += Math.abs(list.get(i).getKey());
            map.put(sum, list.get(i));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

How to express that with  lambda?

Comment: Do it first. Then show us what you have done if you got errors. Not asking us to code it for you.

Comment: Your original loop would benefit from removing the code duplication (calling `list.get(i)` three times and `.getKey()` twice). `for(A a: list) { int key = a.getKey(); if(key != 0) map.put(sum += Math.abs(key), a); }` I doubt that you will find a lambda /stream based solution that can be considered an improvement over this.

Comment: if you read the code completely... yes it is ;-) but... it could still be `Long`... doesn't make sense though, but it could be ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using `foreach` will be more effectively. Not have to be convert everything to a stream when it violate [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) , `for`, `foreach`,`while` loop is not dead. I will giving the stream code later which is a bit more big.

### foreach

```
public Map<Integer, A> toMap(List<A> list) {
    Map<Integer, A> map = new HashMap<>();
    int prevKey = 0;
    for (A item : list) {
        int key = item.getKey();

        if (key != 0) {
            map.put(prevKey += Math.abs(key), item);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

### combine foreach & stream

or you maybe need combine `foreach` & `Stream` to describe that doing two things `filtering` & `mapping`.

```
public Map<Integer, A> toMap(List<A> list) {
    Map<Integer, A> map = new HashMap<>();
    int prevKey = 0;
    for (A item : each(list.stream().filter(it -> it.getKey() != 0))) {
        map.put(prevKey += Math.abs(item.getKey()), item);
    }
    return map;
}

private static <T> Iterable<? extends T> each(Stream<T> stream) {
    return stream::iterator;
}
```

### stream using Stream.collect(Collector)

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;

public Map<Integer, A> toMap(List<A> list) {
    AtomicInteger prevKey = new AtomicInteger(0);
    return list.stream().filter(it -> it.getKey() != 0)
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(curry(prevKey::addAndGet, A::getKey)
                                              ,identity()));
}

// e.g: AtomicInteger.addAndGet(A.getKey())
<T, U, R> Function<T, R> curry(Function<U, R> target, Function<T, U> mapper) {
    return (it) -> target.apply(mapper.apply(it));
}
```

### stream using Stream.collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer)

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Map;

public Map<Integer, A> toMap(List<A> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(it -> it.getKey() != 0).
            collect(Stack::new, this::calculateKey, Stack::addAll).stream().
            collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
}

private void calculateKey(Stack<Entry<Integer, A>> stack, A a) {
    Integer prevKey = stack.isEmpty() ? 0 : stack.peek().getKey();

    Integer key = prevKey + a.getKey();

    stack.push(new SimpleEntry<>(key, a));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
List<Integer> mList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,2,-1,3,0,1);

Map<Integer, Integer> map = mList.stream()
        .filter(i -> i != 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
            int sum = 0;
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Integer integer) {
                sum += integer;
                return sum;
            }
        }, Function.identity()));
```

I've done it for `List<Integer>`, now you should do the same for `List<A>`.

### HINT: Replace `Integer` with `A`.

Comment: The source is a `List<A>`, not a `List<Integer>`…

Comment: @Holger, giving OP a chance to reason about implementing the same for `List<A>`. This is more of an example than a direct answer to the question

Comment: Then you shouldn’t provide spoon-feeding code at all.

Comment: @Holger, I disagree, but your opinion is yours

Comment: It’s just inconsistent. Either, you provide a complete solution or you tell the OP, how to solve on his own. Providing an incomplete solution without any explanation of what it does, is neither.

Comment: @Holger, thanks but I think that last sentence in the answer should be enough to get OP to the right thinking. I will modify it a bit, but the hint is as clear as any other answer I could have given

Comment: Ok, at least it’s sufficient to show that it won’t be a simplification of the original loop code. Maybe that is already helping the OP…